# Adding word like "done" or "added" to the completed row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have this script to add importrange formulas:

```
function setImportRangeFromList1() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
const rows = ss.getRange('A2:D').getValues().filter(r=> r[1])
rows.map(row => SpreadsheetApp.openById(row[0]).getSheetByName(row[1]).getRange(row[2]).setFormula(row[3]))
}
```

and here the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GeVSs3zfuxNYzGybwpTuGGNcwV7U--8VksUHzc5f9p4/edit#gid=0

What i'm looking for is adding word like "done" or "added" to the completed rows, and i want the script not to do these rows again when i run at the next time.
I hope anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function setImportRangeFromList1() {
  const check = "done";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
  const rows = ss.getRange('A2:E').getValues();
  const ranges = rows.map((row, i) => {
    if (row[1] && row[4] != check) {
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(row[0]).getSheetByName(row[1]).getRange(row[2]).setFormula(row[3]);
      return `E${i + 2}`;
    }
    return "";
  }).filter(String);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  ss.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(check);
}
```

- In this modification, when the the column "E" is checked, when the cell value is not `done`, `SpreadsheetApp.openById(row[0]).getSheetByName(row[1]).getRange(row[2]).setFormula(row[3])` is run, and `done` is put to the column "E". By this, when the script is run 2nd time, the rows with `done` in the column "E" are skipped.

#### Note:

- If you want to use `added` instead of `done`, please modify `const check = "done";`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)